# Sum of column for another Group By column in delphi

Tags: sql, delphi

I'm working on a simple delphi form to create a daily balance sheet therefore i'm using a DBGrid having its columns from a table and containing:
date, in, out..what I want to do is group by date and calculate the In and Out for each date in order to make the balance.

Example:

```
     1/01/2013 in (100) out (0),
     1/01/2013 in (200) out (0),
     1/01/2013 in (0) out (100),
```

I want the result to be 1/01/2013 in (300) out (100)

Any help Please cause I'm having trouble after grouping the dates.

Comment: I'm asking for the SQL statement to add to the query to show the desired result in the DBGrid , if i select dates, sum(in) , sum(out) and then group by just dates it wont work

Comment: Got it. See my answer below. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the aggregate expression (`SUM`) more than once:

```
SELECT 
  YourDateField, 
  Sum(in) as InAmount, 
  Sum(Out) as OutAmount,
  Sum(In) - Sum(Out) as Balance
FROM 
  YourTable
GROUP BY
   YourDateField
```

Output:

```
YourDateField    InAmount    OutAmount
=============    ========    =========
01/01/2013       300         100
```

Replace `YourDateField` and `YourTable` with the name of your date column and actual table, of course, and the column aliases (`InAmount`, `OutAmount`, and `Balance`) to whatever you'd like.

Comment: wont there be the exception that the other fields(in, out) are not in the group by statement?

Comment: @Beast No, because those other fields are only used as arguments for a aggregate.

Comment: As ain said, no. But you could always try it yourself very quickly to find out instead of waiting for an answer here. :-) Remember that a `SELECT` can never hurt anything (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` can, but `SELECT` can't), so you can **always** try a `SELECT`. In fact, you always **should** try a `SELECT` before you run a `DELETE`, using the same conditions in the `WHERE` clause, to make sure you've gotten what you're wanting to match first.

Comment: Thank You!! I knew I had to use it but as i said i was not sure if it will work thanks again! works like a charm :)